# Print a string backwards php

Tags: php, string

I want print this string backwards/reverse. I tried this

```
$string = 'HELLO';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string);$i++) {

    $string1[] = $string[$i];

}    

$array =  array_reverse($string1);

foreach ($array as $a)
{
    echo $a;
}
```

and works, but isn't something easier there?

Comment: `echo strrev($string);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)

```
echo strrev($string);
```

Just for kicks, here's an alternative way to do it using arrays like in your example but using `implode()`, `array_reverse()`, and `str_split()`:

```
echo implode('', array_reverse(str_split($string)));
```

Comment: This is easier... Thanks

Comment: You'll find PHP has functions more most common tasks

Comment: *Easy as pie* - Ya gotta love pie!

Comment: I will go with strrev(). a one liner instead of my 'function' sounds better.